# Vim cursorline doesn’t change in autocommand between splits

Tags: macos, vim

I want to change the color of the cursorline between the active and inactive splits in vim.

So I tried

```
augroup CursorLine
    au!
    au VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter * highlight CursorLine ctermfg=black ctermbg=green 
    au WinLeave * highlight CursorLine ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=red 
augroup END
```

And then I opened up vim, did a vertical split `:vsp file`, and then switched between the two splits, but both panes still had the green background, and the inactive one didn’t switch to red upon leaving.

What is wrong with these commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Highlight groups* are global in scope. If you change the colors or formatting of one, *all* occurrences will be updated (on the next screen redraw). In order to support different highlighting for active / non-active elements, you'd need explicit support from Vim for that. This does exist for the *status-line* (in the form of [`hl-StatusLine`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-StatusLine) vs. [`hl-StatusLineNC`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-StatusLineNC) highlight groups), but not for cursorline.

In your case, the `WinLeave` autocmd will be immediately succeeded by the `WinEnter` for the next window, so your attempted change to red basically is ignored.

If you'd like to disable the cursor line for inactive windows instead, that is possible, because the `'cursorline'` option is a window-local one. My [CursorLineCurrentWindow plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4178) makes this really easy.